# Ubuntu 15.10 No USB, No Wifi, No Ethernet

Tags: drivers, usb, ethernet, 15.10

After updating my Dell Latitude from 15.04 to 15.10 I cannot connect through ethernet or wifi and when trying to grab the drivers from another computer and install via USB it won't detect the USB or SD card reader.

So basically I cannot connect or update any devices and was wondering if anyone has any tips before I wipe everything and go back to 15.04??

Comment: post out put of. `lspci` and `lsusb`